# Do resource packs work on Minecraft 1.2.5?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have Minecraft 1.2.5 (I know, it's a really old version) but it was on the demo and when I tried it out it was the FULL VERSION!)

Do resource packs work on 1.2.5? Because I really LOVE the old Minecraft sounds. Otherwise if it doesn't work on my version, is there another way to change the sounds?

Answer (score 4):

If your are referring to resource packs (potential to change both textures *and* sounds, music, models, fonts, ect.), then unfortunately you can't.

Resource packs were added as a feature in 1.6. *texture packs*, (only changes textures) however, then it should work fine, even with texture packs intended for newer versions. Quoting the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Texture_pack#Installation_tips),

> If you have an older version of Minecraft (1.2.5 for example) and you install a Texture pack for a newer version, the texture pack will still run properly, and will ignore the unused items or blocks.

Comment: it's probably best you also add a link where you got the quote from, especially since there are multiple minecraft wikis

Comment: *and you install a Texture pack for a newer version, the texture pack will still run properly, and will ignore the unused items or blocks.* This can change because Minecraft changes the formats for its texture packs, every now and then.

Answer (score 1):

first off, go to finder, and open it. If you already have a window open for something else, right click and click 'open new window'.

secondly, you need to navigate to library. It has a picture on the folder that looks like a public place such as a bank or whatever.

when you get into that folder, click on the application support folder to see all of its contents.

look for the minecraft folder, and click on it.

in the minecraft folder, there is a texture packs folder called 'texturepacks' where you must put your texture packs. These texture packs must be in a .zip format. If your mac converts all zip files into folders, then you must turn all those files back into a zip file! To do this, highlight all the files in your folder, right click, and click 'compress (#) files'. It will compress these files into a zip file named archive, which you can rename to the name of your texture pack.

Once you have the texture pack in a zip file, then drag that zip file into the texturepack directory in your minecraft folder. Then, you can select the texture pack in game from the title screen by clicking on it.

Comment: Would it work if I just added audio files to a texture pack?

Comment: Minecraft 1.2.5 uses texture packs, not resource packs. They do not support sounds.